# How to Make Web View Clickable in Android?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-gridview

Hello i have created one application, in that i getting `Web view` in `Grid view` using custom-adapter.

So how to make `Web view` clickable ?

My code is: Using this i feel the GridView

```
Screen_Shot_Custom_Adapter adapter = new Screen_Shot_Custom_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), screenshotList);               
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The Screen_Shot_Custom_Adapter.java file is:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   
    View vi=convertView;

    if (convertView == null) 
    {           
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_shot_item, null);
        vholder = new ViewHolder();
        vholder.t1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_screen_shot);
        vholder.img=(WebView)vi.findViewById(R.id.webView_screen_Shot);
        vi.setTag(vholder);         
    }
    else 
        vholder = (ViewHolder) (vi.getTag());           
        System.out.println("GridItems:"+gridViewItems);     
        vholder.t1.setText(gridViewItems.get(position).get("time"));
        WebSettings settings = vholder.img.getSettings();
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);        

        vholder.img.loadUrl(gridViewItems.get(position).get("url"));

        return vi;      
}   
static class ViewHolder 
{
    TextView t1;        
    WebView img;
}
```

Comment: Check this Out: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Comment: Hello @kishan, In my application `Web-view` is placed in `screen_shot_item.xml` file and I get this in `Grid-View` using `Custom-Adapter`. `Grid-View is placed in `screen_shot.xml` file. So, I can't create object of `Web-View` directly.

Comment: @SagarZala can you post you code snippest\

Comment: @rajshree, I had posted the code.